# OverflowError using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Having problems connecting to a database using SQLAlchemy. I have used this package for a long time to connect to all the databases we have. Recently was trying to connect to a new database and got the following error:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:password@host/db')
engine.connect()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1778, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 60, in __init__
    self.__connection = connection or engine.raw_connection()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1847, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.unique_connection()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 280, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 644, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 440, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 963, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 285, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 416, in __init__
    exec_once(self.connection, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\event\attr.py", line 250, in exec_once
    self(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\event\attr.py", line 260, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 157, in on_connect
    do_on_connect(conn)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\postgresql\psycopg2.py", line 530, in on_connect
    for fn in fns:
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

The weird part is that for some databases I have the connection works totally fine, but for this specific database I get the OverflowError. Any ideas on why this might be happening? We are using postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the hstore implementation in psycopg2. On connect, psycopg2 tries to use the native hstore implementation which gets the hstore OIDs. These OIDs are out of the C long range values and hence the error is thrown.

You can fix the issue by passing use_native_hstore=False in create_engine

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://username:password@host/db', use_native_hstore=False)
```